# Expressibility and numbering

Tags: logic, computer-science, model-theory

A predicate $P$ is expressible (in PA) if there exists a formula $\phi(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ of $L_A$ such that for all $m_1,\ldots, m_n$ elements of $\mathbb{N}$, we have that $P(m_1,\ldots, m_n)$ holds in $\mathbb{N}$ iff for all $M\models PA$,  $M\models\phi(m_1,\ldots, m_n)$.

How do we show that that the following properties of strings of symbols are expressible?

1. Being a term.
2. Being a formula.
3. Being a sentence.
4. Being a proof in PA.

Comment: We have to show how to find a relevant formula. Details are mostly not hard, but there are lots of them. Key is the Goedel $\beta$-function.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I looked through the properties of the Beta-function but can't find the connection. Would you mind providing your version of what this question asks for? I really dont see what you are trying to do

Comment: Look at one of the textbook presentations I suggest, and all will become clear. There is no fast track here -- you have to do the bookwork.

Answer (score 1):

With a lot of work (not difficult, but a bit tiresome!)

There are two routes to showing those properties are expressible. You can show, relative to a fixed sensible scheme of Gödel-numbering, that they are primitive recursive properties and then show (quite generally) that *any* primitive recursive property is expressible in the language of PA, and expressible by a $\Sigma_1$ wff.

Or, second route, you can proceed more directly, and directly produce $\Delta_0$ wffs which  (relative to a fixed sensible scheme of Gödel-numbering of course) express those properties. (So this is a slightly better result as it gives us $\Delta_0$ rather than $\Sigma_1$ expressibility, though the difference matters little for most purposes.)

For the first route, see e.g. my *Introduction to Gödel's Theorems* (Chs 15 and 19). For the second direct route, see e.g. Christopher Leary, *A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic* (Ch. 4).

[The detailed stories are, however, far too long to give here. Leary takes 30+ pages. I take 12 pages, cutting corners, in my book. I cut even more corners in Ch. 6 of the freely downloadable http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/gwt/GWT.pdf ]